# Querying User input

Tags: mapbasic

I have a small program that selects the table and columns, however I want to query specifically columns that matches the user input.

```
Table_Name = TableInfo(iTabSelection, TAB_INFO_NAME) 'get the Table name from the user input
Colname = ColumnInfo(Table_Name, Col_Name ,COL_INFO_NAME) ' get column name from user input

' then Select  the column user input
Select Colname from TableInfo(iTabSelection, TAB_INFO_NAME) into Temporal
Browse * from Temporal
```

My temporal table is empty.

Comment: Select Colname from TableInfo(iTabSelection, TAB_INFO_NAME) into Temporal

Comment: what is the input from the user? Is that the variables iTabSelection and Col_Name?